# Member Pointer to Base Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, pointers, member

all. I can't undestand why the bellow code need a cast to work. Someone can explain it?

```
class Base {
};

class Derived : public Base {
};

class Class {
public:
    Derived member;
};

...

Derived obj;
Base *ptrObj = &obj; // ok, no cast needed

Derived Class::* ptr = &Class::member; // ok
Base    Class::* ptr = &Class::member; // wrong, need cast, why?
```

Comment: I have never seen that syntax before; someone link me to what it means, it's impossible to search google for these things

Comment: It's a pointer-to-member. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Because if `Base` were allowed (covariant), you could then do this, which is a no-no:

```
Base Class::* ptr = &Class::member;
Class obj;
obj.*ptr = Base();   // <-- assigned a Base into a Derived field?!
```

At the same time, pointers-to-members cannot be contravariant either, because otherwise you could do this, which is also a no-no:

```
struct Class2 {
    Base member;
};

Derived Class2::* ptr2 = &Class2::member;
Class2 obj2;
obj2.member = Base();
Derived& d = obj2.*ptr2;  // <-- assigned a Base into a Derived
```

So, pointers-to-members are neither covariant nor contravariant, but are invariant: the type must match exactly.

Comment: This is not very convincing. You can assign base to derived using normal pointers (otherwise casting derived class pointer to base class pointer would not be allowed), so why not using member pointers?

Comment: This is not a good argument. You can certainly do the following `static_cast<Base &>(obj2.member) = Base();`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got your point Chris, but your first example works for ordinary pointers. Why should it not work for member pointers too? See the code bellow.

```
Derived obj;
Base *ptr = &obj;

*ptr = Base(); // it's weird, but ok
```

The second example will not work even for ordinary pointers, since downcasting is not allowed without cast. So I don't think that should be a explanation.

Comment: Add comments to answers with the "Add comment" function, or edit your question, instead of posting non-answers.

Comment: That is not the same as his first example.  You cannot, using normal pointers, say `Derived* obj = Base()`, since a `Base` is not a `Derived`.  What should happen if `Derived` has `someInt` which is not in `Base`?  Then what should happen when you do `obj->someInt` when `obj` is a `Base`?