# c++ pointer to data member and member type inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointer-to-member

Why it's not allowed to do following conversion of pointer to members:

```
class B {
public:
    virtual void someVirtual() = 0;
};
class D1 : public B{};
class D2 : public B{};
class D3 : public B{};
//all this classes implement someVirtual

struct S {
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
    D3 d3;
    using SptrB = B S::*;
};
```

Now following conversion is allowed:

```
S s;
auto& ref = s.d1; //type D1&
B& bRef = ref; //conversion to B& is OK
bRef.someVirtual();
```

But this one, which semantically is quite the same, is not:

```
auto ptr = &S::d1; //type D1 S::*
S::SptrB bPtr = ptr; //conversion error!
(s.*bPtr).someVirtual();
```

I would like to use such conversion in method `foo(const S& s, S:SptrB ptr)`, to which I could pass `&S::d1`, `&S::d2`, etc. depending on some condition during the runtime.

Comment: There is an identical question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172598/member-pointer-to-base-class but the given answer is wrong.

Comment: So it seems to be a lakuna in Standard... Well, suppose reinterpret_cast<> might work here, but it means stepping on a minefield...